# Regular Expression - All words that begin and end in different letters

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble with this regular expression:

Construct a regular expression defining the following language over alphabet 
Σ = { a,b }

L6 = {All words that begin and end in different letters}

Here are some examples of regular expressions I was able to solve:

```
1. L1 = {all words of even length ending in ab} 
   (aa + ab + ba + bb)*(ab) 

2. L2 = {all words that DO NOT have the substring ab}
   b*a*
```

Comment: Please provide some examples -- your question is not clear (what are L1, L6, R1, etc.?). Also, what have you tried so far? We'll help with a specific problem you're having, but we won't do your work for you.

Comment: Here's one I was able to solve: L2 = {All words of odd length beginning with a}       L2 = a(aa + ab + ba + bb)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work:

```
(a.*b)|(b.*a)
```

Or said in Kleene way:

```
a(a+b)*b+b(a+b)*a
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
"^((a.*b)|(b.*a))$"
```

Comment: Do you mean a.*b  b.*a? he wants start and end to be different

Answer (score 0):

1- Write a Regular expression for each of the following languages: (a)language of all those strings which end with substrings 'ab' and have odd length. (b)language of all those strings which do not contain the substring 'abb'.

2- Construct a deterministic FSA for each of the following languages: (a)languages of all those strings in which second last symbol is 'b'. (b)language of all those strings whose length is odd,but contain even number if b's.

Answer (score 0):

***(aa+ab+ba+bb)∗(a+b)ab***

It can choose any number of even length and have any character from a and b, and then end at string ab.